# Why does IntelliJ mark .java files as executable?

Tags: intellij-idea, cygwin

I'm on a team where some developers are using Eclipse and others are using IntelliJ 12.1.3, all under Windows 7. The Eclipse users are noticing diffs on the properties of .java files. The specific change is visible with cygwin's *ls* command: the executable bit is set on user, group and other. What causes this? Is there a way to tell IntelliJ not to monkey with this bit?

Comment: I've been using intellij in windows and *-nix environments for years and I've never experienced this behavior. I am currently using 12.1.13 too, and still no problems like this. I don't even know how to configure such a thing in IntelliJ, because it just doesn't really play with such things.

Comment: And yet, it is playing with this very thing. How curious.

Comment: It's more likely to be the default permissions you have on your workspace or project directory propagating to new files created by intellij. However, there is a permissions setting under deployment -- if you go into settings and filter by permissions, but it should apply only to things in the target directory that are deployed somewhere, which isn't your source files (unless you have a weird project setup, which you may have because you're on a project with people using eclipse).

Comment: I've started having this happen to me too. did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: @NelsonMonterroso - no, I haven't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74433

> By default, on each save IDEA creates a new file, writes to it, drops original, and renames new file. Setting idea.no.safe.write disables this behavior (original file is just rewritten instead).

Further down..

> It is now configured via GUI - File | Settings | General | Use "safe write". You need to un-check it.

The thread says the root cause is because the original files are over sftp (which wasn't true for me, all my files are on the local filesystem), but this fixed it for me.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'll try this tomorrow when I'm back at work.

Comment: New client, same issue, your answer helped me again. :)

Comment: this is useful for existing files. For new files, IntelliJ insists on creating them as executables - IntelliJ 2017.2.2

Answer (score 3):

On a mac this setting is in a little different place.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

git does not seem to like this safe writing. Every file IntelliJ creates in this way with different permissions shows up as changed (Windows).